# Barplot with ggplot2 using data from read.csv2

Tags: r

I am trying to create a barplot with the ggplot2 library. My data is stored in read.csv2 format.

```
# Library
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse) # function "%>%"

# 1. Read data (comma separated)
data = read.csv2(text = "Age;Frequency
0 - 10;1
11 - 20;5
21 - 30;20
31 - 40;13
41 - 49;1")

# 2. Print table
df <- as.data.frame(data)
df

# 3. Plot bar chart
ggplot(df, aes(x = Age)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  theme_classic()
```

The code runs fine, but it produces a graph that looks like all data are at max all the time.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify your `y` axis as well:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Age, y = Frequency)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
        theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The default value of `geom_bar` plots the frequency of the values which is 1 for all the `Age` values here (Check `table(df$Age)`). You may use `geom_bar` with `stat = 'identity'`

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(Age, Frequency)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
  theme_classic()
```

OR `geom_col` :

```
ggplot(df, aes(Age, Frequency)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  theme_classic()
```